# Can't connect secured Asp.Net Core Web Socket hosted on Azure Web App (using TLS)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, websocket, tls1.2

I spent a whole day searching for a solution but I didn't solve my problem. As you can see from the title, I implemented a basic Web Socket using Asp.Net Core (3.1) framework and I deployed it on Azure (on a Web App service). **I successfully make it works without the TLS protocol** (so I think the ws has been configured in a good manner) but when I try to connect using **wss** I receive this errors on the client side:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException : Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I tried to switch the "HTTPS Only" trigger on azure portal but it keep refusing any client to connect.
[image]

Do you have any idea how to let wss works with Azure Web App? Do I need to configure a certificate? I read that azure provide a certificate if the user didn't have one. Thanks and regards

---

UPDATE: the code has been "copied" from [this great Les Jackson's tutorial](https://dotnetplaybook.com/which-is-best-websockets-or-signalr/) and is available on git hub at [this precise address](https://github.com/binarythistle/S02E03-WebSockets-Vs-SignalR/tree/master/WebSocketServer). The important part of the code is here:

```
/* THIS IS THE SERVER PART WHERE THE CONNECTION IS ACCEPTED */
namespace WebSocketServer.Middleware
{
    public class WebSocketServerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        private WebSocketServerConnectionManager _manager;

        public WebSocketServerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, WebSocketServerConnectionManager manager)
        {
            _next = next;
            _manager = manager;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

                await Receive(webSocket, async (result, buffer) =>
                {
                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Receive->Text");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        await sock.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
/* THIS IS THE STARTUP FILE*/
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddWebSocketServerConnectionManager();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseWebSocketServer();
    }
}
```

```
/* THIS IS THE CLIENT (WRITTEN IN NET FULLFRAMEWORK) */
Console.Write("Connecting....");
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
string wsUri = "wss://testingwebsocket123123.azurewebsites.net";

await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(wsUri), cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine(socket.State);

await Task.Factory.StartNew(
    async () =>
    {
        var rcvBytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        var rcvBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(rcvBytes);
        while (true)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult rcvResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(rcvBuffer, cts.Token);
            byte[] msgBytes = rcvBuffer.Skip(rcvBuffer.Offset).Take(rcvResult.Count).ToArray();
            string rcvMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", rcvMsg);
        }
    }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Did you enable Web Sockets support in WebApp?

Comment: Yes I enabled it and without wss it works fine

Comment: May you please share your code that is related to WebSocket support?

Comment: I added the git hub repository link and I copy-and-paste the relevant part here

Comment: It works fine with the provided javascript client in the [sample](https://github.com/binarythistle/S02E03-WebSockets-Vs-SignalR/tree/master/WebSocketClient). I suspect the error happens because of TLS version when you connect from c# client with full framework. The screenshot of your Azure web app enforces min TLS 1.2. Set that in the .net client like below:
```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
```

Comment: Thanks man! You are right! If I use the javascript client it works. I can't believe it! And YES if I add System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; the fullframework .net client works as well! Please reply to my question so I can mark your answer to be the solution to my problem

Comment: Thanks to @AndriyBilous as well because he is the one who asked me to share the code :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As disussed over the comments, it works fine with the provided javascript client in the [sample](https://github.com/binarythistle/S02E03-WebSockets-Vs-SignalR/tree/master/WebSocketClient). The error in .net client happens because of TLS version when you connect from c# client with full framework. The screenshot of your Azure web app enforces min TLS 1.2. Set that in the .net client like below:

```cs
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```